# How to parse 2 seperate json arrays in response string?

Tags: jquery, json

one of my client application is returning a JSON AS a string, something like below...

```
[
  { 
    "FirstName":"Anurag",
    "LastName":"Chauhan"
  }
]

[
  {
    "City":"XYZ",
    "PinCode":"411006"
  }
]

[
  {
    "Designation":"ABC",
    "PassportNumber":"Something"
  }
]
```

I am not able to figure out any solution for this.

Comment: how about split('\n'), then map with JSON.parse() ?

Comment: This is not valid JSON. JSON requires one root.

Comment: @zhon: Yes you are correct, but this is what i get from my client's DLL.
they might be serializing some DataSet or a Group of DataTables....

Comment: Do you have the entire string or is part of a stream?

Comment: You could help us help you if you added the expected output and the things you have already tried.